# MVC form data submition and then save to database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Model

```
public partial class portfolio
{
    public int portfolio_id { get; set; }
    public int proj_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public virtual project project { get; set; }
}
```

form on which i submit the data and sen to controller

```
<h2>Create View<h2>
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create","Portfolio",FormMethod.Post,new{enctype="multipart/form-data",id="profilepicture"})) 
{

    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Portfolio</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Title", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">

            @Html.TextBox("Name",(String)ViewBag.Name,new {@class="form-control",@disabled="true" })

             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Description", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("URL", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBox("Url",(String)ViewBag.Url, new  { @class = "form-control",@disabled="true"  })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.url, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Image", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="file" name="File" id="File"/>
            @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.image,new { type = "file" })*@
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" /> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Add To Portfolio" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controler action in which i have to post data

```
public ActionResult Create(portfolio por)
    {

        //long unique = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        //int counter = 0;
        //foreach (string fcName in Request.Files)
        //{
        //    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fcName];
        //    string temp = unique + "_" + ++counter + file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf("."));
        //    string url = "~/Content/images" + temp;
        //    file.SaveAs(Request.MapPath(url));
        //    por.image= url;


        //}
        if(por.image.content)
        bool result = _DaoPortfolio.AddProject(por);
        if (result == true)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
        }
        else
            return View();


      }
```

Comment: What is your question? What problems are you having and what is not working?

Comment: Was there a question about that?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idon't know what problem you face but try this...its work for me

Here WorkType is My Model

public partial class WorkType

```
{
    public WorkType()
    {
        this.Works = new HashSet<Work>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Work> Works { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                WorkType worktype = new WorkType();
                worktype.Type = collection["Type"].ToString();

                db.Entry(worktype).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

AND View :

@using (Html.BeginForm())

{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<fieldset>
    <legend>WorkType</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Work Type")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Type)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>

    <div class="span7">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="span2 btn btn-default" />
        <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Slider")'" class="btn btn-primary">
            Back to List
        </button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

}

Comment: thankx now my image path is save in my database
can you please tell me how i can retrive these image on view while showing the list of images